# How to identify last integer value in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to add a string before the last integer value in string

```
string = "298 Anna salai Chennai 607106"
```

Expected result:

```
"298 Anna salai Chennai TN 607106"
```

Comment: What is the distinction between "add some words before the last integer value" and "add some string before the integer value"? They sound like the exact same thing. And I can't understand what you mean by "I have to X, but I want to Y" when X and Y are exactly the same. Can you explain  your problem better?

Comment: Any code suggestions by yourself? This is not a platform which does all your homework for you. If you don't push some effort by yourself, how can you expect someone else to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You should use regex for this:

```
import re
string = "298 Anna salai Chennai 607106"
string = re.sub(r'(\d+)$', r'TN \1', string)
print(string)
```

If you want to do repeated searching and replacing, you should compile the pattern first.

```
import re
string1 = "298 Anna salai Chennai 607106"
string2 = "111 ABC 123456"
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)$')
repl = r'TN \1'
string1 = re.sub(pattern, repl, string1)
string2 = re.sub(pattern, repl, string2)

print(string1)
print(string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just find the index of substring and create new string using splits:

```
m = re.search(r'(\d+)\D*$',string)
number = m.group()    
i = string.find(number)
new_string = string[:i] + "TN " + string[i:]
```

Comment: The last integer value in a string is not necessarily 607106. The solution surely should work for any integer value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do such kind of tasks with regular expressions (regex) 

Read more about [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

```
import re
re.search(r'(\d+)\D+$', string).group(1)
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

to get the last item (that is a number) in a string all you have to do is use split

```
last_value_integer = int(string.split(' ')[len(string.split(' '))-1])
```